# Why do electrons flow from a specific object to another and not in any other way?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electrons, charge

When we rub our hair with a balloon, the electrons move from our hair to the balloon. So what is the reason that they don't get transferred from the balloon to the hair and please also tell me why do the electrons move at all.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect

Answer (score 0):

Electrons like other charged bodies move from rest only due to an applied external potential.(In Elementary Terms) It depends on chemical properties of materials involved which decide the potential change or transfer of charge.

P.S. Your Name and Time of Post Suggest you are a Physics Student preparing for JEE/NEET. Don't sweat it! It's the least important part of electrostatics and rarely become part of the questions

Answer (score 0):

Electrons are attracted to the atomic or molecular "remainings" differently, depending on particular molecules. If two different molecules get in touch, there is some probability that electrons will be attached to the most attractive core; thus charges get devided in space. Even wind may carry away some charges from the Earth.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that they don't get transferred from the balloon to the hair is because of high electron affinity of the balloon than hair. and for the second question you ask why do the electrons move at all the reason is simple again because of being attracted towards highly electronegative thing they move.

Answer (score 0):

The electrons you are dealing with are bound to atoms, and to material structures.  The force that keeps them there is the electromagnetic force.  With this said, if you apply a large enough electrostatic force (ie. a static electric field then you may overcome the force that binds them to those materials, and consequently the electrons will move.

When you rub a balloon against your hair, electrons can move from your hair to the balloon via "triboelectric charging," which is one way to generate a static charge. The reason electrons transfer from your hair to the balloon rather than the other way around has to do with the nature of the materials involved how much "static charge" they each build up.